# How to reduce image height in this case?

Tags: html, css

I'm getting too large image height fo some reason.

The relevant code is

[image]

```
<!-- Main Images -->
<div class="item_image" style="height:auto">


        <div class="item_arrow_left" style="height:auto">
        <i class="sprite_vi_arrow_left" style="margin-top: 200px"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="image_container">

<img src="{{image_url}}" id="main_image_0" alt="{{ad.title}}" title="Click for next image">
        {% for im in imv %}
<img src="{{im}}" class="hidden" id="main_image_{{loop.index}}" alt="{{ad.title}}" class="thumb_image_single" title="Click for next image">

    {% endfor %}

    </div>
    <div class="item_arrow_right" style="height:auto">
        <i class="sprite_vi_arrow_right" style="margin-top: 200px"></i>
    </div>


</div>
```

A live view of the problem is [here](http://www.koolbusiness.com/vi/7639193.html). What can be done to resolve it? I already worked on the problem and got a solution for the view with many photos, but this is the view with just a single image so it appears that I did not think of everything.

Comment: try this: `<img src="{{image_url}}" id="main_image_0" alt="{{ad.title}}" title="Click for next image" style="height:200px">` (or any other height that will fix in your site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as netblognet said your problem isent images height you have some element style is your code that element style you write in your code or some js code applying this.
that is efacting you display i have remove these code from site in firebug

here is code i chang

```
<i class="sprite_vi_arrow_left" style="margin-top: 200px"></i> 
//remove this element style         style="margin-top: 200px"

<i class="sprite_vi_arrow_right" style="margin-top: 200px"></i>
//remove this element style         style="margin-top: 200px"
```

after that remove this from css

```
.item_image .item_arrow_right i {
float: right;
margin-right: 6px;
margin-top: 225px;// remove this line 
}
```

your code using some extra margin-top 
after doing these steps your site should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem isn't the image's height, but the margin-top of the -Tags!

Try to remove or lower the margin-top and you'll get you expected result.

```
<i class="sprite_vi_arrow_left" style="margin-top: 100px"></i>
```

(Of course you'll have to fix also the css of the sprite_vi_arrow_right element.)